# Reading multiple urls from text file and find RESOLVE results using pycurl

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, pycurl

I need to get the result of all urls present in text file with looks something like below

```
www.google.com
example.com
facebook.com
```

with more than 1000 URL's in file and i need  to parse one by one url through the file to test results

```
buf = BytesIO()
with open(data.txt) as fi:
    files = fi.readlines()
    for web in files:
    
        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://'+ web )
        c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
        c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
        c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 3)
        c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buf)
        c.setopt(c.RESOLVE, [ web + ':443:203.210.7.46'])
        c.perform()
```

it gives an **Traceback c.perform() pycurl.error:(3,'')**

but if i just put one url directly in **c.URL** it works perfectly. Can someone please help me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you get from `readlines` end with a newline character `\n`, so the first iteration of the loop would set `c.URL` to:

```
'https://www.google.com\n'
```

and pycurl is telling you that's unexpected: error 3 is [CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), "The URL was not properly formatted".

Calling `web.strip()` will get you the line without the terminating newline character (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)).